# How to ignore fields with sscanf (%* is rejected)

Tags: go

I wish to ignore a particular field whilst processing a string with sscanf.

Man page for sscanf says

`An optional '*' assignment-suppression character: scanf() reads input as directed by the conversion specification, but discards the input.  No corresponding pointer argument is required, and this specification is not included in the count of successful assignments returned by scanf().`

Attempting to use this in Golang, to ignore the 3rd field:

```
if c, err := fmt.Sscanf(str, " %s %d %*d %d ", &iface.Name, &iface.BTx, &iface.BytesRx); err != nil || c != 3 {
```

compiles OK, but at runtime err is set to:

`bad verb %* for integer`

Golang doco doesn't specifically mention the %* conversion specification, but it does say,

`Package fmt implements formatted I/O with functions analogous to C's printf and scanf.`

It doesn't indicate that %* is not implemented, so... Am I doing it wrong? Or has it just been quietly omitted? ...but then, why does it compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no such verb (as the format specifiers are called in the `fmt` package) for this task. What you can do however, is specifying some verb and ignoring its value. This is not particularly memory friendly, though. Ideally this would work:

```
fmt.Scan(&a, _, &b)
```

Sadly, it doesn't. So your next best option would be to declare the variables and ignore the one
you don't want:

```
var a,b,c int
fmt.Scanf("%d %v %d", &a, &b, &c)
fmt.Println(a,c)
```

`%v` would read a space separated token. Depending on what you're scanning on, you may fast forward the
stream to the position you need to scan on. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12369469/1643939) 
for details on seeking in buffers. If you're using stdio or you don't know which length your input may
have, you seem to be out of luck here.

> It doesn't indicate that %* is not implemented, so... Am I doing it
>   wrong? Or has it just been quietly omitted? ...but then, why does it
>   compile?

It compiles because for the compiler a format string is just a string like any other. The content of that string is evaluated at run time by functions of the `fmt` package. Some C compilers may check format strings
for correctness, but this is [a feature](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html#format), not the norm. With go, the [go vet](http://golang.org/cmd/vet/) command will try to warn you about format string errors with mismatched arguments.

**Edit**:

For the special case of needing to parse a row of integers and just caring for some of them, you
can use `fmt.Scan` in combination with a slice of integers. The following example reads 3 integers 
from stdin and stores them in the slice named `vals`:

```
ints := make([]interface{}, 3)
vals := make([]int, len(ints))

for i, _ := range ints {
    ints[i] = interface{}(&vals[i])
}

fmt.Scan(ints...)
fmt.Println(vals)
```

This is probably shorter than the conventional split/trim/strconv chain. It makes a slice of pointers
which each points to a value in `vals`. `fmt.Scan` then fills these pointers. With this you can even
ignore most of the values by assigning the same pointer over and over for the values you don't want:

```
ignored := 0

for i, _ := range ints {
    if(i == 0 || i == 2) {
        ints[i] = interface{}(&vals[i])
    } else {
        ints[i] = interface{}(&ignored)
    }
}
```

The example above would assign the address of `ignore` to all values except the first and the second, thus
effectively ignoring them by overwriting.

Comment: Thanks for you response.
I haven't quite followed. To plainly state what I am intending - I wish to discard the 3rd field of the input.
Ie, suppress the conversion to a parameter.

Your line of code appears to provide a width precision for the conversion of that field to a parameter.

Comment: Oh, it seems that I misunderstood your question, I will update my answer.

Comment: Cheers... "can't be done" is not the answer I wanted to hear, but it is an answer nonetheless!
My example here was trimmed for ease of viewing - I'm actually parsing the output of /proc/net/dev and am only interested in fields 1,2 and 10. I'm not about to declare 7 unneeded ints... I have a multi-line solution using string. Split, Fields, Trim and strconv.Atoi -- in C, I would have used a single sscanf.