# String Decoding in Golang

Tags: string, go, decoding, string-decoding

In Ruby, I'm using the string.unpack method to decode some data. I'm migrating this code into a Golang app, however I can't find a corresponding method in the standard library?

The ruby code is: `str.unpack('>LLLff')`

What is the best way to implement this in Go?

---

Example data:

```
]\x00\x00@\x00\x8C\xD2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h.\x9FAjK\x8FG\xC0T\x87UX\xA1CH\xB7\x80\x82}\xBB\xF9\x8F\xBAcqF{\xE31/Zx\xC0\x04\xFF\b\xA0\xBD\a\x9E\x0F\x14c+\b\xD3\xE8\xE1\xC2\x1C7\xBCmd/j\xC1H\x191~\x91F\b5-\x8A\x9F(\\\xF1\x16/\x0F\xEA\xD9\x94rV\xEC\xBB\xCB\x12qJ\x05\b\x04 {R\xB8\xA4\xA9\xD0)v\x97<\xCA\x92\xB6U\b)\x1D\x1D\xF1\x00\xE4U\x8DB\x16/v\xEC[bLTW\xB2\xFB\x0F\x91\x05\xAA\x9C\xBD\x8E\x1A\xFB\xDFUJ\xB8\xDE\xF5m\xC8Z\xC1\v\\|\r;\xB6\xE6\xA6\x13o\x91\xE1\xBA\x9An\x8B\x01W\xB9\"\x12+\x9B[\xC7\xCD\xC2O+\f^|\xE1G\x86.%m\xB2x\xF1j\e\"\xE41Bu_\x16J\xE4M\x7F\xC5U[\xB9\xD0\xC7\xECu\xE53\xB4)\xD5\x80|\xB7.\xD2\f\xF3\x16\x8B\xE3\x13\x81\x02:5\x88\x0F
```

Should map to:
     `[1073741917, 13798400, 0, 2.4178516392292583e+24, 5.851859700165677e+25]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unpack various form of integers in a byte buffer in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357865/how-do-i-unpack-various-form-of-integers-in-a-byte-buffer-in-golang)

Comment: I don't think its quite a duplicate, and it will be useful for those coming from Ruby to see it answered in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "log"
)

type UnpackedThing struct {
    First  uint32
    Second uint32
    Third  uint32

    Fourth float32
    Fifth  float32
}

func main() {
    input := bytes.NewBufferString("]\x00\x00@\x00\x8C\xD2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h.\x9FAjK\x8FG\xC0T\x87UX\xA1CH\xB7\x80\x82}\xBB\xF9\x8F\xBAcqF{\xE31/Zx\xC0\x04\xFF\b\xA0\xBD\a\x9E\x0F\x14c+\b\xD3\xE8\xE1\xC2\x1C7\xBCmd/j\xC1H\x191~\x91F\b5-\x8A\x9F(\\\xF1\x16/\x0F\xEA\xD9\x94rV\xEC\xBB\xCB\x12qJ\x05\b\x04 {R\xB8\xA4\xA9\xD0)v\x97<\xCA\x92\xB6U\b)\x1D\x1D\xF1\x00\xE4U\x8DB\x16/v\xEC[bLTW\xB2\xFB\x0F\x91\x05\xAA\x9C\xBD\x8E\x1A\xFB\xDFUJ\xB8\xDE\xF5m\xC8Z\xC1\v\\|\r;\xB6\xE6\xA6\x13o\x91\xE1\xBA\x9An\x8B\x01W\xB9\"\x12+\x9B[\xC7\xCD\xC2O+\f^|\xE1G\x86.%m\xB2x\xF1j\x1B\"\xE41Bu_\x16J\xE4M\x7F\xC5U[\xB9\xD0\xC7\xECu\xE53\xB4)\xD5\x80|\xB7.\xD2\f\xF3\x16\x8B\xE3\x13\x81\x02:5\x88\x0F")
    var unpacked UnpackedThing

    err := binary.Read(input, binary.LittleEndian, &unpacked)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("[%d, %d, %d, %f, %f]\n",
        unpacked.First, unpacked.Second, unpacked.Third, unpacked.Fourth, unpacked.Fifth)
}
```

We're creating a struct that properly represents the binary format, then using `binary.Read()` to read our bytes into this struct. One thing to note is that golang's strings don't understand `\e`, so it must be converted to `\x1b`.

Output:

```
*@x~/go/src/stackoverflow.com/binunpack⦕ go run main.go
2018/10/07 17:39:16 [1073741917, 13798400, 0, 2417851639229258349412352.000000, 58518597001656773736660992.000000]
*@x~/go/src/stackoverflow.com/binunpack⦕
```

Comment: Huh, that's cool. I've used encoding/binary before, but somehow up until now I never noticed that it handled structs :)

Comment: Yeah, I just came across it the other day myself :)